# MobileNet transfer learning in Keras for object localization extraction - loss computed as NaN

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to use Keras and its MobileNet implementation to do object localization (output the x/y coordinates of a few features, instead of classes) and I'm running into some likely very basic issue that I can't figure out.

My code looks like this:

```py
# =============================
# Load MobileNet and change the top layers.
model = applications.MobileNet(weights="imagenet",
                               include_top=False,
                               input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

# Freeze all the layers except the very last 5.
for layer in model.layers[:-5]:
  layer.trainable = False

# Adding custom Layers at the end, after the last Conv2D layer.
x = model.output

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Reshape((1, 1, 1024))(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Conv2D(1024, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv_preds')(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)

# I'd like this to output 4 variables, two pairs of x/y coordinates
x = Dense(PREDICT_SIZE, activation="sigmoid")(x)
predictions = Reshape((PREDICT_SIZE,))(x)

# =============================
# Create the new final model.
model_final = Model(input = model.input, output = predictions)

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  '''Trying to compute the Euclidian distance as a Loss Function'''
  return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1))

model_final.compile(loss = custom_loss,
                    optimizer = optimizers.adam(lr=0.0001),
                    metrics=["accuracy"])
```

With this model, then I load the data and try to train it.

```py
x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = load_data(DATASET_DIR)

# This load_data is my own implementation. It returns the images
# as tensors.
# ==> x_train[0].shape= (224, 224, 3)
#
# y_train and y_val look like this:
# ==> y_train[0]= [ 0.182  -0.0933  0.072  -0.0453]
#
# holding values in the [0, 1] interval for where the pixel
# is relative to the width/height of the image.
#
model_final.fit(x_train, y_train,
                batch_size=batch_size, epochs=5, shuffle=False,
                validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Unfortunately, what I get when I run this model to train, I get something like this:

```sh
Train on 45 samples, validate on 5 samples
Epoch 1/5
16/45 [=========>....................] - ETA: 2s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0625
32/45 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0312
45/45 [==============================] - 4s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0222 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
16/45 [=========>....................] - ETA: 2s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0625
32/45 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0312
45/45 [==============================] - 4s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0222 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/5
```

I'm at a loss about why my loss value is "nan". I must be doing something wrong, and I've tried to change everything - the loss function, the shape of the output... but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE: it seems like the issue is in the way I load_data.**

If I create the image data like this it fails and results in loss:nan

```py
i = pil_image.open(img_filename)
img = image.load_img(img_filename, target_size=(224, 224))

x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input(x)

x_train = np.append(x_train, x, axis=0)
```

but if I do something trivial like this, 'fit' works just fine and computes real values for loss:

```
x_train = np.random.random((100, 224, 224, 3))
```

*sigh* I wonder what's happening...

**UPDATE #2: I figured out what the issue was**

Documenting this here in case it helps anybody.

The way to properly generate the input tensors for MobileNet is this one:

```py
test_img=[]
for i in range(len(test)):
    temp_img=image.load_img(test_path+test['filename'][i],target_size=(224,224))
    temp_img=image.img_to_array(temp_img)
    test_img.append(temp_img)

test_img=np.array(test_img) 
test_img=preprocess_input(test_img)
```

Notice how making it into a numpy.array and running preprocess_input happens on the whole batch of images. Doing it image by image seems to not have worked (what I was doing before).

Hope this helps somebody someday.

Comment: 1) you use `model_final = Model(input = model.input, output = predictions)`, but where is `model.input` defined? 2) try with a built-in loss function first (e.g. MSE), and only when you are sure that everything else works as expected move on to your custom loss...

Comment: thanks for the reply! 1) model.input is the input for the MobileNet keras model that I'm loading... that seems common in all the transfer learning code I've seen around this. 2) I've tried loss="mean_squared_error", loss="categorical_crossentropy", other built in ones and I get the same "nan"... maybe my y_train, y_val are not the right kind of objects?